# how can i get user location for webview app in react native? for showing current user location on google map

Tags: react-native, webview, geolocation, expo

am newbie at react native and i have a task to do .. please help me...
i have an app smiller to uber .. and i want to take user current location to show his location then the destination .. idk how to do this :(

```
import React , {useState , useEffect , useRef} from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { StyleSheet , BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {

  const webviewref = useRef(null);
  const [canGoBack , setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
  const [canGoForward , setCanForward] = useState(false);
  const [currentUrl , setCurrentUrl] = useState('https://my-website');

  const backAction = () => {
    if(canGoBack){
      webviewref.current.goBack();
    }else{
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
    return true
  }

  useEffect(()=>{

    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
    () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

  },[ canGoBack ])

  return (
    <WebView 

      ref={webviewref}
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: currentUrl }}
      onNavigationStateChange={navState =>{

        setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack);
        setCanForward(navState.canGoForward);
        setCurrentUrl(navState.url);

      }}
    />
  );}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's current location by adding fine location on android manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` then the location access permission will automatically appear when the page is opened.
And to get location coordinates in webview, you can use Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() API